# Error(before_avatar_post_process) using paperclip gem. I am using rails 4.2 and ruby 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, paperclip, image-uploading

I am beginner in ruby on rails. I ran into an error while using paperclip gem. [image]

User model is

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_secure_password

attr_accessor :validate_password

has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
has_many :replys, dependent: :destroy

has_attached_file :profile_picture, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }
validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/



validates :registered_id, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true, :length => { :is => 10 }, 
                                                                  :on => :create
validates :first_name, :presence => true
validates :last_name, :presence => true
validates :email, :format => { :with => /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i }
validates :password, :length => {:in => 6..20},  if: lambda { |u| u.validate_password == true }
end
```

and migration is generated by command line

```
"rails generate paperclip user profile_picture"
```

when I remove the line

```
validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
```

in User model, it doesn't show the error. If I add that line It is showing error in

```
NoMethodError in Posts#index

Showing /home/akash/rails/forum/app/views/posts/index.html.erb where line #41 raised:
```

please help me solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope you already follow all the beginning steps and ran migration there is nor `:avatar` there is `:profile_picture` as per your generator it will create attachment field for `:profile_picture`

From your code

```
validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
```

should change to

```
validates_attachment_content_type :profile_picture, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
```